# Jenkins - Do not run build steps if there are no changes in git

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

I was setting up jenkins to create war builds using git and maven . I have created a hook in bitbucket to invoke jenkins build also mentioned the branch name in jenkins to build in a specific branch . Issue is that whenever there is a new commit in any of the branches jenkins is building and redeploying the war file .
What i need is , jenkins should abort the build if there are not change in git . Please help.

EDIT:
I did tried in maven level using plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <forced>false</forced>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>`
```

Still maven is building the war file if there are "No sources to compile."

Answer (score 0):

When you [configure BitBucket to call a jenkins job](https://gist.github.com/joseraya/6838271), that will call it on any push (regerdless of the branch)

Your jenkins job should be in charge of:

- step 1: analyzing the json payload (which is, since July 2015, a "Fuller, more descriptive payload")
- step 2: if the right branch is detected in the payload, trigger a *second* Jenkins job in charge of fetching the git repo and launching a build.
  For instance, you can use the [BuildResultTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin).

Comment: Looks like this is the only way . Thanks for the help.
Some heavy work needed . Do you have any link that says how to parse the json payload ?